# Debian VM in qemu stuck in infinite boot loop?

Tags: linux, debian, qemu, arm

So recently I tried to set up a Debian vm with qemu on an arm-arch pi...the problem is when I run the x86_64 arch vm with debian, it gets stuck in an infinite loop at boot. Even when I select recovery mode at the grub menu, the loop still incurs. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: You're running qemu on an RPi. Ouch! That would hardly have enough power to get just qemu up, not to say getting enough memory to start a live Debian.  It is probably not stuck, it is just using swap as memory (which added to the emulation lag would give you around x500 speed decrease)

Comment: @grochmal do you know of any x86_64 distros that might have a chance at running on qemu?

Comment: You're really going overkill with trying to emulate x86_64 on an RPi.  Maybe (and that's a big maybe) Knoppix, or the Arch Linux installation disk, can fit in the available memory/processing power.  But forget about getting any graphical server (Xorg) running on qemu on an RPi.  (you need a decent machine to properly run virtualisation)

Comment: @grochmal yeah I know that trying this is overkill, but thanks for the suggestions. I didn't really need the graphical portion anyways. I was really only looking for simple command line to run simple x86_64 programs on

Comment: I actually decided to run DSL instead as an x86 platform and it works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help though!